# Cannot use acmsmall's narrowfig tegether with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, acm

I'm trying the use the `narrowfig` environment from the [`acmsmall`](http://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/article-templates/acmsmall.zip) class. The following works without problems:

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}
\begin{document}
\begin{narrowfig}{.5\linewidth}
  Foo
  \caption{Bar}
\end{narrowfig}
\end{document}
```

However, this breaks down with the following error when `hyperref` is included:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
 
                   {
l.6   \caption{Bar}
```

I suppose `hyperref` is redefining some of the figure machinery in a way incompatible with `acmsmall` but, alas, I do not posses the necessary LaTeX knowledge to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: and where do you get `acmsmall`? It does not seem to be included in a standard LaTeX installation

Comment: @daleif: There's a link in my post.

Comment: Ahh never saw that

Comment: The class redefines caption. If you are writing an article to be published by amc and they do not provide any information about `hyperref`, then perhaps don't use it.

Comment: @daleif: That would indeed be a fail-safe last resort option. But since I like the functionality provided by hyperref, I was hoping to find a workaround here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acmsmall` expects that `\r@@nf<n>` (where `<n>` is the number of the figure) expands to

```
{<figure number>}{<page number>}
```

in order to set a conditional depending on the odd or even page number. With `hyperref` the expansion of `\r@@nf<n>` is, instead,

```
{<figure number>}{<page number>}{...}{...}{...}
```

with five braced groups instead of two. This breaks the mechanism.

The simplest workaround is using the `refcount` package, that knows by itself whether `hyperref` has been loaded and does the right thing in every case.

We need to change the `\@seteven` macro in the class:

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to fill with some mock text

\makeatletter
\def\@seteven{%
    \@nfeventrue
    \edef\@tmpnf{\getpagerefnumber{@nf\thefigure}}%
    \ifodd\@tmpnf\relax
        \@nfevenfalse
    \fi
    \label{@nf\thefigure}%
    \edef\@tmpnfx{\if@nfeven e\else o\fi}%
    \edef\@tmpnf{%
        \write\@unused{%
            \noexpand\ifodd \noexpand\c@page
                \noexpand\if \@tmpnfx e%
                    \noexpand\@nfmsg{\thefigure}
                \noexpand\fi
            \noexpand\else
                \noexpand\if \@tmpnfx o%
                    \noexpand\@nfmsg{\thefigure}%
                \noexpand\fi
            \noexpand\fi
        }%
    }%
    \@tmpnf
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{narrowfig}{.5\linewidth}[htp]
  Foo
  \caption{Bar}
\end{narrowfig}

\lipsum

\begin{narrowfig}{.5\linewidth}[htp]
  Foo
  \caption{Bar}
\end{narrowfig}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly the kind of LaTeX-wizardry I was hoping to find here!